# Prove that if $p \mid \dfrac{a^n+1}{a+1}$, then $p \mid (-a)^n-1$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number $\leq n$ where $n>1$ is an odd prime. Prove that if $p \mid \dfrac{a^n+1}{a+1}$, then $p \mid (-a)^n-1$.

We can write $$\dfrac{a^n+1}{a+1} = a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}+\cdots-a+1,$$ but how do we continue from here?

Comment: You cannot write that unless $n$ is odd

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $(-a)^n-1=-a^n-1=-(a^n+1)$, so isn't the claim trivial?

Comment: @lulu How is it trivial?

Comment: $p\,|\,\frac mn\implies p\,|\,m$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p|\frac{a^n+1}{a+1}$, then there exists an integer $k$ such that $kp=\frac{a^n+1}{a+1}$. Thus, $kp(a+1)=a^n+1$, so $-kp(a+1)=-a^n-1=(-a)^n-1$ where the last equality follows since $n$ is odd. The statement $-kp(a+1)=(-a)^n-1$ says $p|(-a)^n-1$.